# The GET_LOCK() and RELEASE_LOCK() functions are taking too long

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, mysql-5.7

We are trying to use the MySQL's locking functions GET_LOCK() and RELEASE_LOCK() in our Spring Java application. The code we are using is defined in a procedure for both seperately which simply invoke from our Java code (the queries inside the proc are given below).

We have been monitoring the execution time of these functions and found that at times it takes a millisecond to execute but, at other times, this takes around 400 to 600 ms. I have tried the following approaches but there hasn't been much of a difference:

1. Use "Do" in place of select with these functions.
2. Using an int data type of the key which we are using as lock string.
3. Decreasing the length of lock string.

I am using a timeout of 0 to avoid connections being locked.

#### Questions

- Can anyone please suggest me a way to optimize this?
- Is there a way of optimizing innodb buffer pool or something related to these configurations?

Please do let me know if any other input is required from my end.

#### Code

Please find below some proc code and stats for your reference:

```
get_Name_lock:

-- Using select

Select get_lock(Name,0) into c_Name_flag;

-- Using Do

Do get_lock(Name,0) ;
```

Stored proc:

```
release_Name_lock :

-- Using select

Select release_lock(Name) into c_Name_flag;

-- Using Do

Do release_lock(Name);
```

- Request rate: (around) 10 requests/sec
- MySQL version: 5.7.19-log

Comment: Why are explicit locks needed? Can something be changed in the procedure to more fully utilize aspects of MVCC to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Please back up in the question -- Why are you using GET_LOCK (etc)?  It is essentially _never_ needed with InnoDB because of the existence of robust "transactions".  Perhaps we can help you code your app a different way.

Comment: Hey Danblack and Rick , the thing is we have some java service calls and some a procedure which we have to run for each thread and they have to be thread safe bcos data is fetched in java ,modified and then sent to PRC . The service call and other operations need to be done and that's why I cant depend on the proc wholly .

Comment: Also , we have a way of using locking in java but we are currently trying to look for a way of doing it such that we can scale it up horizontally

Comment: by "fetched [...], modified and set to the RPC", so it is a message/batch queue? (if so use a message queue implementation like RabbitMQ not SQL), or is the original data modified as a results of the RPC, so 'SELECT ... FOR UPDATE, {RPC} call, UPDATE ... , COMMIT' would be a pattern.

Comment: The data is modified yes , that's why we do a fetch first from db .

Comment: I am not sure about performance of select for update. Funny thing is wasnt sure about the performance of get_lock but here it is ,giving absurd results . I am just not sure if I am doing it right . I think I am missing on some part because I have seen in text books and online that get_lock and releaee_lock takes 1 ms .

Comment: The short "text book" time might be when there is no existing lock. Or it could be fudged. This is why Rick and I are trying to get robust transactional way of doing this for you, so you can increase parallelism, delay horizontal scaling and make it easier when you do. On select for update - same performance as the original data you are getting, just it puts a different type of lock down when it does. So please, more details on data structures, data needed for the RPC, and what exact things do not need to be RPCed twice.

Comment: I am actually more in favor of select for update or better calling it innodb row lock as that is something i am sure of . As in this case of get_lock and release_lock, i cannot do much because of this abstraction . I will do one thing. I will try to make up a locking algo using select for update and a table for maintaining the lock entries . Will load test it and then let you know. Thanks for the help :)